# error str-int y no deja convertirlo

Tags: python

```
diccionario={1: ['0.18', '0.26', '0.41', '0.11', '0.05'],  2: ['0.34', '0.07', '0.39', '0.16', '0.03']}

for persona in range (1,numpersonas+1):
    filtrada2= [(f,(pes1, pes2, pes3, pes4, pes5)) for (f,(pes1, pes2, pes3, pes4, pes5)) in diccionario.items() if f==persona]
```

> ```
> listas>>[1, ('0.18', '0.26', '0.41', '0.11', '0.05'))]
>       >>[(2, ('0.34', '0.07', '0.39', '0.16', '0.03'))]
> ```

```
 for fila in filtrada2:
         crit1= crit01+fila[1][0]
         hoja2['K2']= crit1
```

pero fila[1][0] me sale como str y no me deja convertirlo a int, me da el siguiente error

```
>>>  crit1= crit01+fila[1][0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

alguien podría ayudarme???

```
int(fila[1][0])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-105-e424d02841a0>", line 1, in <module>
    int(fila[1][0])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.18'
```

Comment: Los elementos no son enteros. Son `float`. Aparte de eso, para quien venga detrás, intenta mejorar la redacción de la pregunta, que es un caos de trozos de código, ejemplos de salida (mal formateada), errores, y la pregunta perdida por el medio.

Comment: es la primera vez que escribo y no sé muy bien cómo escribir el código... lo que me pasa es que de tener una variable float paso a tener str al asignarle la posición de una lista. Mi pregunta es cómo puedo hacer para poder volver a convertirlo a float

Comment: Respecto a tu duda, `float(dato_que_es_un_str)`. Respecto al formato de la pregunta, cuando pegues código debes después seleccionarlo y pulsar el botón que contiene "{}". Esto te lo indenta cuatro espacios que es la forma de señalar que debe ser presentado con fuente de ancho fijo. Pero no sólo me refería al formato. ¿Qué son las "listas" que muestras? ¿No sería más claro volcar la variable `filtrada2`? ¿Por qué tras la pregunta "Alguien podría ayudarme" muestras otro trozo de código, que no explicas, y que produce una excepción. A eso me refiero co lo de mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Y por cierto, bienvenida a StackOverflow. Puedes echar un vistazo a este [documento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) que te resume cómo funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observaciones varias respecto a tu código y a tu pregunta:

1. Los datos que tienes en el diccionario son listas de cadenas. Al usar comillas como en `'0.18'`, el dato es de tipo `str`. Por tanto el dato que tienes en `lista[1][0]` es una cadena, porque *ya en origen* (dentro del diccionario inicial) lo era, no porque se haya convertido a cadena al pasarlo a una lista, como mencionas en un comentario.
2. Si no quieres que los datos, ya en origen, sean cadenas sino floats, no los pongas entre comillas en el diccionario.
3. Si los datos de entrada son cadenas y no puedes evitarlo, puedes convertirlos a float cuando necesites operar con ellos mediante `float(dato)`. Lo que tú has intentado `int(dato)` no funciona porque la cadena contiene el carácter `"."` que no puede aparecer en un entero (aunque sí en un float). También puedes convertirlos a `float` mientras los estás guardando en la lista `filtrada2` (al final de esta respuesta muestro cómo).

Por otro lado, tu bucle:

```
for persona in range (1,numpersonas+1):
    filtrada2= [(f,(pes1, pes2, pes3, pes4, pes5)) for (f,(pes1, pes2, pes3, pes4, pes5)) in diccionario.items() if f==persona]
```

aparentemente lo que quiere hacer es convertir el diccionario en una lista. Supongo que lo haces para que dentro de ella aparezcan los datos ordenados por la clave, es decir, primero la lista cuya clave en el diccionario es `1`, luego la que usa clave `2`, etc. Entiendo que haces esto porque los diccionarios no garantizan el orden.

Sin embargo la forma en que lo haces es bastante ineficiente, e incorrecta:

- Haces un bucle en el que `persona` va tomando los valores 1, 2.. que entiendo que corresponden a las claves de tu diccionario.
- Para cada uno, recorees el diccionario entero mediante una *list comprehension* para buscar qué elemento tiene una clave que coincida con `persona` ¿por qué? ¿No es mucho más sencillo hacer `diccionario[persona]` para obtenerlo, en vez de recorrer todo el diccionario para quedarse sólo con el caso en que `f==persona`?
- Cada iteración del bucle guarda el resultado de la *list comprehension* en la misma variable (`filtrada2`). Cada nueva iteración por tanto hace que se pierda el resultado de la iteración anterior. Al salir del bucle tendrás sólo la lista correspondiente a la última persona.

Sospecho que no quieres quedarte sólo con la última persona, ya que más adelante intentas iterar por `filtrada2` como si tuviera varias filas. Si lo que quieres es ir acumulando en una lista los resultados del bucle anterior, entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
filtrada2 = []
for persona in range(1, numpersonas+1):
    filtrada2.append((persona, diccionario[persona]))
```

Resultado:

```
>>> filtrada2
[(1, ['0.18', '0.26', '0.41', '0.11', '0.05']), (2, ['0.34', '0.07', '0.39', '0.16', '0.03'])]
```

Pero si la razón de hacer esto era que simplemente querías cambiar el diccionario por una lista, de modo que salga ordenada por el número de personas, podrías cambiar todo el bucle anterior por una línea:

```
filtrada2 = sorted(diccionario.items())
```

ya que `diccionario.items()` te da una lista de tuplas en la que cada tupla tiene dos elementos, el primero la clave del diccionario (numero de persona) y el segundo el valor (lista de cadenas), y luego `sorted()` te ordena esa lista por el primer elemento de cada tupla, que es el número de persona.

Ya que más adelante vas a procesar esa lista, no quieres que los datos sean cadenas, sino que necesitas que sean `float`. Como ya dije al principio si puedes cambiar el diccionario de entrada para quitarle las comillas, ya lo tendrías. Si no, entonces tienes dos opciones:

1. Convertirlo a float cuando vayas a operar con el dato (es decir `float(fila[1][i])`, por ejemplo.
2. Convertir los datos a float mientras estás creando la lista `filtrada2`.

La segunda opción también puede hacerse de muchas formas. Una de ellas, quizás la más legible:

```
filtrada2 = []
for persona in range(1, numpersonas+1):
    filtrada2.append((persona, 
                      [float(dato) for dato in diccionario[persona]])
                    )
```

resultado:

```
>>> filtrada2
[(1, [0.18, 0.26, 0.41, 0.11, 0.05]), (2, [0.34, 0.07, 0.39, 0.16, 0.03])]
```